# lexicographically smallest string based on another string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is the algorithm to generate lexicographically smallest string satisfying condition based on input string consists of `> and <` only?

for example

```
if input is "<<" then answer is "abc" // explanation "a<b<c"--> "a" is less than "b" and so does "c"
if input is "<>" then answer is "aba" // explanation "a<b>a"
if input is "<>><<" then answer is "acbabc" // explanation "a<c>b>a<b<c"
```

This question was asked in one of coding interview.
Constraint: length of input string is 2<= len(input) <= 10^6

**Any hint to solve this** question will also be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a greedy approach(not tested).

For every `<`, we only need to be concerned about how many `>` are there *consecutively* to the right + 1(here, +1 is for current char in relation with previous char of `<`).

We also initialize a `current_char = a` variable.

Let's take `<>><<` for example. The counts would look like below:

```
 <  >  >  <  <
 3        1  1
```

We now move from left to right of the array and assign values based on `current_char + count` value. For now, assume `a + 3 = c` considering current character too.

For consecutive `>` places, we just decrease `current_char` by 1.

```
  <  >  >  <  <
  3        1  1
a c  b  a  b  c
```